# Wait for WKWebView evaluateJavaScript to finish

Tags: swift, xcode, webkit

I have a problem that's been irritating me for a couple of days now. I'm trying to work with a `WKWebView` in my Swift project. Below is my code:

```
var items: [String] = []
    for i in 0...8 {
        web_view.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('channels-content-item yt-shelf-grid-item')[\(i)].innerHTML") { (result, error) in
            //print(result ?? "nil")
            //print(error ?? "nil")

            let string_result: String = String(describing: result!)
            items.append(string_result)
            num += 1
            //print(string_result)

        }
    }

    print(items)
```

My problem is the fact that the program won't wait for the evaluateJavaScript functions to finish before going to the print(items), even though the items array gets populated via these functions. Any way I can get this to work?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? You cant use `dispatch_semaphore_wait` as this has to run in the `main queue`

Answer (score 0):

What is inside of your completion handler I think runs on a different thread, meaning it is running AFTER your print happens. Since injecting javascript takes longer, your print is most likely always going to happen first.